# Magento 2: How to find which config causing error “Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded” when trying to serialize checkout config

Tags: magento2, utf-8

I'm on Magneto 2.3.4. In `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml` there's a line like this:

```
        window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;
```

Following the function, it comes down to `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Onepage.php::getSerializedCheckoutConfig()`

And the serialize function is in `vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/JsonHexTag.php`

I added `json_last_error_msg()` to the exception message, and basically the error message is now:

```
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): 
Unable to serialize value. Error:Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

How to quickly find the checkout configuration value or key that is having malformed UTF-8 characters? Or how to quickly fix this in database?

Comment: You should know how to use XDebug. It's easier for you to check root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I faced the same issue. In my case, a custom payment config encryption caused that issue. Please check the config with encryption, for example: token, password,...

Comment: Great suggestion, i was able to debug and find the malformed config value using mb_detect_encoding($suspiciousString, 'UTF-8', true)